# request.getSession(false) creating session

Tags: java

I am trying to create a secure login page for my web app in java but when I directly access the authenticated page i.e main.jsp, the program instead of redirecting to home page, generates a new session and gets authenticated automatically

```
    import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger; 
import java.security.MessageDigest; 
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class login extends HttpServlet
{
    public String generateMD5(String rawPassword)
    {
        try { 

            // Static getInstance method is called with hashing MD5 
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); 

            // digest() method is called to calculate message digest 
            // of an input digest() return array of byte 
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(rawPassword.getBytes()); 

            // Convert byte array into signum representation 
            BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest); 

            // Convert message digest into hex value 
            String hashtext = no.toString(16); 
            while (hashtext.length() < 32) { 
                hashtext = "0" + hashtext; 
            } 
            return hashtext; 
        } 

        // For specifying wrong message digest algorithms 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(e); 
        }
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String email=req.getParameter("email");
        String password= req.getParameter("password");
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/passwordmanager";
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","1234");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        //password=generateMD5(password);
            String check="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='"+email+"' AND password='"+password+"';";
            ResultSet rp = st.executeQuery( check );
            if(rp.next())
            {
                HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
                // session.setAttribute(email,password);
                // req.setAttribute("session",session);
                //RequestDispatcher vf = req.getRequestDispatcher("verifySession");
                RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
                //vf.include(req,res);
                rd.forward(req,res);

            }
            else
            {


                RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("failure");
                rd.forward(req,res);

                }

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  



    }
}
```

**main.jsp**

```
<

%@ page import="java.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.servlet.*" %>
<%
    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(false);
    if(session1==null || !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid())
    {response.sendRedirect("index.html");}
    out.println(session1.getId());
%>
<html>
    <body>
        You successfully logged in!
        <form method="POST" action="logOut">
            <button type="submit"> Log Out </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also if I change the name of session from "session1" to "session", it gives the error of duplicate local variable I dont know how is it duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**session is default object in jsp**

```
%@ page import="java.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.servlet.*" %>
<%

    if(session==null || !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid())
    {response.sendRedirect("index.html");}
    out.println(session.getId());
%>
<html>
    <body>
        You successfully logged in!
        <form method="POST" action="logOut">
            <button type="submit"> Log Out </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**For Example**

```
<%
  if (session == null)
  {
    String address = websiteContext + "/login.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(address);
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
  }
%>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but I still cant get the fact that why HttpSession sess= request.getSession(false); was creating a new session for me when there didnt exist one

Answer (score 1):

> HttpSession sess= request.getSession(false);
>
> **> *because jsp is having default session which already have implementation so when you use HttpSession sess=
>   request.getSession(false); it will create new object***